# Understanding RNN/LSTM

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to understand how to use RNN/LSTM; but I cannot understand some concepts related to topology. I found really useful information in this article:
http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/. But then, when comparing that topology [1](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/img/LSTM3-chain.png) to the one Alex Graves says in his LSTM writing[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbUQF.jpg), and the one described here [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUIFm.jpg), we can see the differences (in the first one the inputs never go to previous states, whereas they do in the other two topologies).
What is going on?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There exist several LSTM variants, this may explain the difference you have observed.

{1} gives a list:

> 4.3. LSTM Variants
>
> The vanilla LSTM from Section 2 is referred as Vanilla (V). The
>   derived eight variants of the V architecture are the following:
>
> 1. No Input Gate (NIG)
> 2. No Forget Gate (NFG)
> 3. No Output Gate (NOG)
> 4. No Input Activation Function (NIAF)
> 5. No Output Activation Function (NOAF)
> 6. No Peepholes (NP)
> 7. Coupled Input and Forget Gate (CIFG)
> 8. Full Gate Recurrence (FGR)
>
> The first six variants are self-explanatory. The CIFG variant uses
>   only one gate for gating both the input and the cell recurrent
>   self-connection (an LSTM modification proposed in GRU (Cho et al.,
>   2014)). This is equivalent to setting $f_t = 1 − i_t$ instead of
>   learning the forget gate weights independently. The FGR variant adds
>   recurrent connections between all the gates as in the original
>   formulation of the LSTM (Hochreiter & Schmidhuber, 1997). It adds nine
>   additional recurrent weight matrices, thus significantly increasing
>   the number of parameters.

---

References:

- {1} Klaus Greff, Rupesh Kumar Srivastava, Jan Koutník, Bas R. Steunebrink, Jürgen Schmidhuber
  LSTM: A Search Space Odyssey. https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.04069

Comment: I see. But I have something unclear: For time series, If I am training my model with 400 sequences of length 6 (data of 6 weeks, the label will be the 7th week value), and in order to predict a value in the future I just use 1 sequence of length 6: am I really using 400 states? Why did I calculate the value of those weights if then I am just feeding one sequence?